# How to drop type in Oracle if the name of type has plus sign? (addition sign, "+")

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11gr2

How to drop type in Oracle if the name of the type has character '+'? I don't know how it was created, but I cannot drop it.

Here is my type:

```
SQL> SELECT type_name FROM user_types WHERE type_name = 'SYSTP975ZkBBFSYqy+bxofjABNA==';

TYPE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTP975ZkBBFSYqy+bxofjABNA==
```

When I try to drop like the following, it shows error under + symbol

```
SQL> DROP TYPE SYSTP975ZkBBFSYqy+bxofjABNA==;
DROP TYPE SYSTP975ZkBBFSYqy+bxofjABNA==
                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

When I try to drop type by quoting the name, it shows error under ' symbol

```
SQL> DROP TYPE 'SYSTP975ZkBBFSYqy+bxofjABNA==';
DROP TYPE 'SYSTP975ZkBBFSYqy+bxofjABNA=='
          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02302: invalid or missing type name


SQL> DROP TYPE 'SYSTP975ZkBBFSYqy\+bxofjABNA==';
DROP TYPE 'SYSTP975ZkBBFSYqy\+bxofjABNA=='
          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02302: invalid or missing type name
```

Comment: you need to specify schema name

Comment: Use double quotes.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to enclose it in `"`.

```
DROP TYPE "SYSTP975ZkBBFSYqy+bxofjABNA==";
```

Comment: I couldn't imagine that it could be so easy :) Thank you!